# How could a WCF service call was returned from server side in debugging, but no response in the traffic tracking tool?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

Recently a WCF web service call in our Mobile App reported 'The network connection was lost' error in some case.
I debugged it in  the server side and found it was successfully returned.
But in the traffic tracking tool there was no HTTP response.
This function performed inconsistently when the parameter value varied.
Sometimes it worked sometimes it didn't.

The web service was bound in webHttpBinding and transportMode=buffered.
I have tried to change the maxBufferSize and maxReceivedMessageSize to max length, but it did not work.

Does anyone knows what's the possibly reason?

Comment: Have you looked at WCF Tracing?  This sort of error commonly occurs when there is an error in serialization (missing `KnownType`, etc...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comment by Mitch, the best way to determine the root cause of the issue is to enable WCF Tracing on the host service, reproduce the issue and then review the WCF trace file.

Oftentimes, the WCF Trace log will reveal issues that previously seemed “hidden”.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx